# Set return type from Type that passed into method

Tags: c#

Method `resolve()` return instance of initialized object from Dictionary, but my question is: is there any way to simplify `resolve()` method in a way that we still pass type as argument but after we don't need cast it. I thought about generic resolution but for `resolve<ClassAbraKadabra>(typeof(ClassAbraKadabra))` looks repetitive and cant simplified.

```
class Foo {
   //something here
}

//reality
class Resolver{
   public void proc() {
      Foo foo = (Foo) resolve(typeof(Foo));
   }
   private object resolve(Type type) {
      var obj = getInstanceOfObjectFromMapByType(type):
      return obj;
   }
}

//expected
class Resolver{
   public void proc() {
      Foo foo = resolve(typeof(Foo));
   }
   private ??? resolve(Type type) {
      //magic here
   }
}

//generic way
class Resolver{
   public void proc() {
      Foo foo = resolve<Foo>(typeof(Foo));
   }
   private T resolve<T>(Type type) {
      var obj = getInstanceOfObjectFromMapByType(type):
      return (T)obj;
   }
}
```

Comment: You can just make a method with no arguments and still pass the generic type and it can be resolved.  I've done this many times.  Example:  ```resolve<Foo>();```

Answer (score 1):

Your generic way was almost there, you don't need to pass in the type just do a `typeof(T)` from inside the generic method.

```
//generic way
class Resolver{
   public void proc() {
      Foo foo = resolve<Foo>();
   }
   private T resolve<T>() {
      var obj = getInstanceOfObjectFromMapByType(typeof(T)):
      return (T)obj;
   }
}
```

If you really must pass in type then the "reality" way is the only option, you have to do the cast at a higher level and just try to return a common interface that is still useful.